# Excel MRound logic in sql how it possible below output?

Tags: sql

Below table column is input

| Column1 |
| --- |
| 248111 |
| 217811 |
| 354594 |
| 230950 |

I need the following output

| result |
| --- |
| 250000 |
| 200000 |
| 350000 |
| 250000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure if there is any built-in functions for this but the math behind is
`base * round(value/base)`

Here, let's take your example. The `value` corresponds to the data in the column and `base` is to what you are rounding off. In your case, `base = 50000` since, all your output values are multiples of `50000` and for the first row `value = 248111`

Thus,

```
base * round(value/base)

round(248111/50000) = 5
5*50000 = 25000 => is your answer
```

I have created a procedure for this logic in SQL server. Below is the snippet,

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION Mround(
    @val int,
    @base int
)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN   
    RETURN @base * round((@val/cast(@base as float)),0)
END;
```

And you can call the function like

```
SELECT [Schema_name.]Mround(Coulmn1,50000)
FROM [table_name]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: SELECT [dbo].Mround(Coulmn1,50000)
FROM [table_name]

Comment: yes, in your case, schema_name is 'dbo' . It's a default schema created by sql sever.